# VPN server inside AWS VPC. Propagate VPN route to all instances

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, vpn, openvpn, amazon-vpc

So i configured OpenVPN server as an EC2 instance. I would like to access all of my ec2 instances inside VPC. I did push the route to my vpn clients about vpc subnet. How can I propagate a route to my vpn subnet to all of my ec2 instances without manually doing so ?

Comment: I hate it when people answer "why don't you use Y" when you're asking about X, yet AWS has an Out Of the Box solution for VPN connections; a VPN gateway can be configured in order to link your network to one or more VPCs, all natively and beautifully bound to EC2 routing tables. You can set it up on your side using racoon or freeswan.

Comment: As a quick solution I wanted to setup OpenVPN. I think you are offering using ipsec solition. I gues I could. About your comment, what do you mean by `VPN gateway` There is a `Virtual Private GW` and `Customer GW` which I think both should be used with `VPN Connection` feature, which essentially connects them to each other. But I think that this solution would require a VPN box outside AWS. I want to have a VPN server inside AWS. Correct me if I am missing something. I am really new to all of this.

Comment: Yes by VPN Gateway I meant the whole thing, you need to declare a Virtual Private GW to which you'll attach a VPN Connection, check this very well done tutorial which I first used when I created my first VPN Gateway https://openfoo.org/blog/amazon_vpc_with_linux.html

Comment: your answer did make me research the entire thing and it is fantastic. Cheers for that. I will promote Pavel's answer as it solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create route table for your subnet in VPC. It can look like:

`Destination:10.0.1.0/24 Target:eni-0227407b / i-95f276e5`

That will push route that will tell all instances in targeted subnet to route requests to `10.0.1.0/24` to `eni-0227407b` interface.

Thing like this works for me at least with OpenVPN.

Comment: I tried this sulution. I got the route set up: `10.8.0.0/16 eni-8116dfde / i-86b49b0a Active No`. But it does say that all routes in that table are not propagates. And when i created a new ec2 instance - it could not ping 10.8.0.1 nor there was a route to my `10.8.0.0/16` subnet in `route -n`. What am I missing ?

Comment: Have you associated route table with subnet on AWS?

Comment: I do have only one table. And as it is `Main` I assume it should work. I ll try doing that.

Comment: Ok. I did associate that routing tables with all subnets. Still no result.

Comment: here is the link to the screenshot: http://pasteboard.co/56mbSGSco.png

Comment: Do you have iptables rules correctly set up on your server with OpenVPN?

Comment: @Katafalkas did you disable the source/dest IP check on the openvpn instance?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yup, I missed that. Every tutorial specifically mentioned this and I still missed and forgot it :D Cheers dude.

Comment: So you're good, now?

Comment: Yeah. Got all sorts of other problems. But this one was fixed :) cheers